# Git branch naming (containing version)

Tags: git, gerrit

My Git branch name has some problems.

I wanted to rename remote branch 'a/develop' to 'a/develop/1.0'.

But couldn't rename. :(

my code is below.

**git branch -m a/develop/1.0**

**git push origin :a/develop a/develop/1.0**

The error message is **failed to lock**

what problem is my naming code?
Please reply my question.
Thanks!~

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(It's not clear from your question which command is failing; I'm assuming the first one is failing.)

The fundamental problem here is that the name `a/develop` is "in the way" of the `a/develop/` directory/folder (choose your favorite word, both mean the same thing here) that must exist in order for the name `a/develop/1.0` to exist.

Now, clearly *after* renaming `a/develop` to `a/develop/1.0`, `a/develop` itself is no longer in use as a branch name.  But *before* the rename completes, `a/develop` *is* in the way.  If Git were doing the "create directory/folder and rename" as a single operation, it would work—but it's not: Git first tries to create the directory/folder, but `a/develop` is in the way, so that part fails, and then Git never renames `a/develop`.

The solution is to rename `a/develop` to something—anything—else, such as `a/b`, temporarily.  Now `a/develop` does not exist and it becomes possible to rename `a/b` to `a/develop/1.0`.

Be aware that if you do this, and if `a/develop` exists on your "upstream" (to which you `git push`), the upstream will have the same problem: it won't be able to create `a/develop/1.0` because its own `a/develop` will be in the way.  You will need the same two step process (rename or delete, and let that finish, before renaming or creating).